# Trying to find ubuntu-8.10-umpc-i386.img

Tags: 8.10

I am trying to find a version of Ubuntu 8.10 that was configured specifically for UMPCs (as described [here](http://people.canonical.com/~ogra/mobile/), but it appears to have completely disappeared off the internet; it's no longer on [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/ubuntu-umpc/intrepid/current/) and the only torrent I can find has zero seeders. It boggles the mind that an operating system can just vanish into thin air. Anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some searching but try the following:

- [mirrors.mit.edu](ftp://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu-cdimage.bak/releases/intrepid/release/ubuntu-8.10-umpc-i386.img)
- [solar-one.mit.edu](ftp://solar-one.mit.edu/ubuntu-cdimage.bak/releases/intrepid/release/ubuntu-8.10-umpc-i386.img)
- [solar-two.mit.edu](ftp://solar-two.mit.edu/ubuntu-cdimage.bak/releases/intrepid/release/ubuntu-8.10-umpc-i386.img)

which worked well on my system. Google tends to index ftp sites poorly and this is usually where the old gems are hiding :)